# Can I jailbreak a 3G iPad 2 running iOS 4.3.5?

Tags: ipad, jailbreak, ios

I have a 3G iPad 2 running iOS 4.3.5. I wanted to jailbreak it but most articles point to 4.3.3 and the downgrade isn't applicable to my model .

I wanted to know if it is possible to jailbreak my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They point to 4.3.3 because that's the last version that supported an untethered jailbreak. Any version after 4.3.3 cannot be jailbroken: http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Jailbreak